# What is the minimum length of SOSL search expression

Tags: apex, sosl

While performing SOSL for one character I got exception 
`"search term must be longer than one character"`, with more than one characters query is working fine.

Is there any document from Salesforce which specify minimum character length.

Answer (score 2):

I cant find documentation for the minimum search length in a SOSL query.
Testing in Dev console I found that is set in 2 chars.

Seems logical, when you use global search on SFDC, you get a error message if your search pattern has less than 2 chars (Your search term must have 2 or more characters.)

For less than 2 chars the option is using SOQL.